# Regex in Python to extract and sum all the numbers following strings that match certain format

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like this one:

**DL21032953:200**,SWUS202106150117:72,SWUS202106150052:120,SWUS202106150055:108,SWUS202106150047:60,SWUS202106150045:72,SWUS202106150088:108,SWUS202106150085:120,SWUS202106150081:108,SWUS202106150075:108,SWUS202106150078:108,SWUS202106150165:96,SWUS202106150205:72,SWUS202106150168:84,SWUS202106150167:72,SWUS202106150227:48,**DL21047822:240**

I'd like to extract all the numbers after "DL...:" and sum them together. For example, in this case, the numbers in bold: `200 + 240 = 440`. Is there a way to perform such an operation?

Comment: What regex have you tried, and how did they come up short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like `DL\d+:(\d+)`, then convert to int `map(int` and `sum`

```
import re

s = "DL21032953:200,SWUS2...    50227:48,DL21047822:240"
numbers = sum(map(int, re.findall(r"DL\d+:(\d+)", s)))
print(numbers)  # 440
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you! I forgot about the "re.findall" part in my previous attempts...

Answer (score 1):

Your best shot is something like this:

```
import re
mystr = "DL21032953:200,SWUS202106150117:72,SWUS202106150052:120,SWUS202106150055:108,SWUS202106150047:60,SWUS202106150045:72,SWUS202106150088:108,SWUS202106150085:120,SWUS202106150081:108,SWUS202106150075:108,SWUS202106150078:108,SWUS202106150165:96,SWUS202106150205:72,SWUS202106150168:84,SWUS202106150167:72,SWUS202106150227:48,DL21047822:240"

sum(int(n) for n in re.findall(r'DL\d+:(\d+)\b', mystr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst realising that the OP requested an answer using regex -- below is a non-regex approach.

```
import json

PATTERN = "DL"

input = "DL21032953:200,SWUS202106150117:72,SWUS202106150052:120,SWUS202106150055:108,SWUS202106150047:60,SWUS202106150045:72,SWUS202106150088:108,SWUS202106150085:120,SWUS202106150081:108,SWUS202106150075:108,SWUS202106150078:108,SWUS202106150165:96,SWUS202106150205:72,SWUS202106150168:84,SWUS202106150167:72,SWUS202106150227:48,DL21047822:240"

# Create a dict from input string
d = dict(map(lambda x: x.split(":"), input.split(",")))

# Type conversion for dict values
d_converted = {k: int(v) for k, v in d.items()}

# Filter converted dict by pattern
d_filtered = dict(
    filter(lambda x: x[0].startswith(PATTERN) == True, d_converted.items())
)

# Sum the filtered dict values
sum(d_filtered.values())  # 440
```